# How to convert String in number : create wrong number

Tags: php

In my table I have a price could be string or number but I tried to convert the string in number but it does work.

At the origin the number is  like that inside my table (on row for the name and one row for the price)

```
Apple iPhone 13 128 Go Minuit   |  1 379€00
Apple iPhone 14 128 Go Minuit   |  1 379€00
Apple iPhone 14 128 Go Lumière Stellaire    |  919€00
Apple iPhone 14 Pro 128 Go Noir Sidéral |  919€00
```

After refactoring I have this and you can see if it's a numeric (num) or a string

```
Apple iPhone 13 128 Go Minuit   |  1 379.00
Apple iPhone 14 128 Go Minuit   |  1 379.00
Apple iPhone 14 128 Go Lumière Stellaire    |  919.00 num
Apple iPhone 14 Pro 128 Go Noir Sidéral   |  919.00 num
```

If I tried to applied that :

I also tried with floatval but does not work

```
if (is_string($price_format)) {
  $price_format = number_format((float)$price_format, 2, '.', '');
}
```

The result is :

```
Apple iPhone 13 128 Go Minuit   |  1.00 num
Apple iPhone 14 128 Go Minuit   |  1.00 num
Apple iPhone 14 128 Go Lumière Stellaire |  919.00 num
```

As you see I have 1.00 and not the price but everything is numeric

the result I need is a price number like that 1 379.00 and not a string

Below my approach

```
foreach ($result as $item) {
  $price = $item['1'];

  $convert_array = ['$', '€', '£', '¥', '₩', '₹', '₽', '฿', '₺', '₴'];

  foreach ($convert_array as $symbol) {
    if (strpos($price, $symbol) !== false) {
      $price = str_replace($symbol, '.', $price);
      $price = preg_replace('/\. /', '', $price, 1);
      $price = str_replace(',', '.', $price);
      break;
    }
  }

  $price_format = trim($price);

  if (substr($price_format, -1) == '.') {
    $price_format = substr($price_format, 0, -1);
  }

/*
  if (is_string($price_format)) {
    $price_format = number_format((float)$price_format, 2, '.', '');
  }
*/
  if (is_numeric($price_format)) {
    $price_format = $price_format . ' num';
  }
  print_r($price_format);
}
```

[Image result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwNP2.png)

Comment: `Apple iPhone 13 128 Go Minuit   1 379€00`...is this all one field, or several fields? It's really not clear. Please format your data more clearly. You have shown us a code block which takes `$result` as an input, but we cannot tell precisely what the contents of `$result` is. You can  [edit] your post.

Comment: `After refactoring I have this`...is this the result you want, or the data you've already got at the start of the code shown? Your description is unclear. Please see also [ask] if you need more guidance. Thankyou.

Comment: I@ADyson it's several field one for the name and one for the price

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. So here's a runnable demo: https://3v4l.org/IBKcU

Comment: ok, tk  do not know this tool, ok. I hope it can help

Comment: Why use `preg_replace()` when there are no special regexp characters? It's the same as just `str_replace('. ', '', $price, 1)`

Comment: You can replace that entire loop with `preg_replace('/[$€£¥₩₹₽฿₺₴]\s/, '', $price, 1)`

Comment: @Barmar because Ihave this error : Uncaught Error: str_replace(): Argument #4 ($count) cannot be passed by referenc

Comment: @Barmar, the convertion does not work with preg_replace

Comment: I see, `str_replace()` doesn't allow you to specify a limit. That's an output argument containing the number of replacements made.

Comment: _"At the origin the number is like that inside my table"_ - just to be clear, we are talking about your _database_ table here? Then your grave mistake is that you stored already _formatted_ values in there, instead of a proper numeric value. _"(on row for the name and one row for the price)"_ - what you call rows, are actually columns.

Comment: @CBroe Oups,your are right.

Answer (score 1):

If your expected thousand separator for the input number is space you can try, removing the space first (anything after the space is ignored by the `float` conversion) and then adding it again using `' '` as the last parameter of `number_format()`:

```
if (is_string($price_format)) {
    $price_format = number_format((float)str_replace(' ','',$price_format), 2, '.', ' ');
  }
```

In the example here (https://3v4l.org/OCSWN) the result is:

```
1 379.00
1 379.00
919.00 num
919.00 num
```

Comment: No it does not work I have 1.00 num instead 1 379.00 with your approach

Comment: Did you change the same edits to the call to `number_format`? if you can check in the example link I've posted, the result is `1 379.00`. You can post an updated version of your code to see what happened.

Comment: @F.lgor - I Included an image inside the post above with your approach : Image result.
When I have a string the convert give 1 (suppose all is removed after)